# Error in node.js.. Cannot set header after they are sent to clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, ejs

So i am building a blog and I am trying to render different paths using the router parameter but it keeps bring up this error every time I try to print another route. Cant really explain more but i will place my code here.

```js
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import lodash from "lodash";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const _ = lodash();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

let globalarray = [];

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index.ejs", {
    arr: globalarray,
  });
});

app.get("/contact", (req, res) => {
  res.render("contact.ejs");
});

app.get("/create", (req, res) => {
  res.render("create.ejs");
});

app.post("/submit", (req, res) => {
  const posts = {
    category: req.body["category"],
    title: req.body["title"],
    post: req.body["post"],
  };

  globalarray.push(posts);
  res.redirect("/");
});

app.get("/globalarray/:pathName", (req, res) => {
  let requestedName = _.lowerCase(req.params.pathName);

  globalarray.forEach((item) => {
    if (requestedName === _.lowerCase(item.category)) {
      res.render("post.ejs");
    }
  });
});
```

This last part is where the problem is. Please I need an assist with this.

I have tried returning, but nothing is working.

Comment: Check how many times `res.render("post.ejs")` is being called. Seems like it might be called multiple times (which would give you this type of error).

Comment: You cannot call `res.render()` in a loop. Seems more like you want `res.render('post.ejs', { arr: globalarray.filter({ category }) => requestedName === _.lowerCase(category)) })`

Comment: Please Phill can you help me write this solution well cause I only bits of it. It’s not really clear.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your error is likely coming from the code below. [res.render()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) automatically calls res.send() so the payload is being sent back after the first iteration.

On the second iteration when the response has already been sent you can't modify the request in-flight. To fix this you'll have to make sure all the logic for creating many post (views) exists on your "post.ejs" template.

So you would want your posts.ejs to accept an array of items and iterate over it and generate the appropriate html for each item in the array.

```
globalarray.forEach((item)=>{
    if(requestedName ===  _.lowerCase(item.category)){
        res.render("post.ejs")
    }
})
```

Comment: So how would I make I post.ejs accept an array of items to iterate over??